# how to convert objects properties into array with destruction es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a belwo collection of objects assigned in

```
  products:{id: null, name: 6801},
     {id: null, name: 6802},
     {id: null, name: 6805}
```

I need to use map function and iterate the name need to convert into array of strings.

current code is written in 0 : `{names: 6197} 1 : {names: 6801} 2 : {names: 6802}`

but i need the below format

```
names:[6802,6802,6805],
    products.map(({name: names}) => ({names}));
```

Comment: Such as: `let names = products.map(p => p.name);`

Comment: @tymeJv which is assigned to names

Comment: Assuming you mean "destructuring" instead of "destruction", is there some reason you are doing it that way instead of `p => p.name`?  If you need destructuring you would do `({name: n} => n)`.  What is the point of this question?

Comment: which is not return in array of string [6802,6803] and return in `0
:
{name: 6197}
1
:
{domicile: 6801}
2
:
{name: 6802}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
products.map(({name}) => name);
```

Don't put the result value in braces, that would form another object literal.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let productNamesArray = products.map(ele=>{return ele.name;});
```